# Update or create does not update and only creates

Tags: python, django, django-views, backend

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@login_required
def edit_question(request):
    req = json.loads(request.body)
    question_no = req["question_no"]
    guided_answers=req["guided_answer"]

    for guided_answer in guided_answers:
        obj, created= models.ModelAnswer.objects.update_or_create(
            question_id=models.Questions.objects.get(pk=question_no),
            model_ans= guided_answer["model_ans"],
            answer_mark=guided_answer["answer_mark"],
            defaults={
                'answer_mark':guided_answer["answer_mark"],
                'model_ans':guided_answer["model_ans"],
            }
        )
    return success({"res": True})
```

What i am trying to do is update or create based off checking whether the model answer already exist or not in the database however everytime i try to update an existing model answer it creates it into a new one, i do not understand why it does not filter out if it exists or not,i do not know whether it is my filter or my defaults that is wrong

Comment: Looks like your trouble is: you put the same vale in `kwargs` and in `defaults`.

Comment: is that not how you write the defaults to determine check whether the object exist in database or not? and also do you think i should edit the question to show the models as well?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why exactly you ran into this problem but you have a problem in code..you are filtering ModelAnswer by question_id but you are giving it a queryset.
this code(Questions.objects.get(pk=question_no)) returns a queryset object or None if DoesNotExist and you are passing it to question_id..
you can change question_id to question or you can first get question and check if exists or not and if it exists you can pass its id to question_id..
but first solution is better i think.

Comment: `get` - return object not a queryset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

Comment: ok but you cant use an object as question_id.